# iOS Build Issue after Flutter upgrade

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios-build

I thought of updating the flutter version with all dependencies, as some of my dependencies were having bugs... **After updating my Flutter version to 3.16.0**, I solved the issues raised in Android part, but I'm not that strong in the iOS part of Flutter... So, I'm **unable to solve the error raised from iOS part**...
I referred to some other available questions in StackOverflow and even done rebuilding the ios folder, still the same issue...

I created a new flutter_application and it works fine... Now, I need to modify the existing project and make sure that it works fine in both Android & iOS...
Kindly help me with this...

While trying to debug the app, I get the below issue in my console...

[image]

And this is the Podfile, I'm using from the beginning of this project

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  pod 'GoogleUtilities'
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 3.4.3', '< 4.0'
end


target 'ImageNotification' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'GoogleUtilities'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
        'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1',

        ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
        'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',
       
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
        'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=1',
      ]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe this thread on github helps? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/120404